# Jquery is reading only first element in loop

Tags: php, jquery

Here in this code, when I am displaying array in a form. I need to iterate over array, so that I can perform my code operation. 
My problem is jquery is only fetching first element. Can someone suggest what need to be done here, so that I can access all the elements.

```
<?php foreach($packs as $item) { ?>                                                 
  <br/>
  <label> Fee: </label>  
  <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value=<?php echo $item ?> />
  <input type="text" id="discount" placeholder="discount" name="discount"  value="10%" />
  <br/>                                                 
<?php } ?>
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {          
  $('#price').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: You're repeating the same `id` on multiple elements as they're created in your loop. This is invalid as they *have* to be unique. Use a `class` instead.

Comment: "have to be" => "should be"

Comment: @Taplar not sure what you mean. The `id` cannot be repeated. It has to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my code, I need to iterate the array, and find the sum of product of price and discount. Can you suggest me what should i do, as both are input type.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Give `$('[id="price"]')` or `$("#price, #price")` a whirl and see if your opinion on that matter changes.  Ids **should** be unique, but technically there are work arounds. To say something *must* be something, infers there is no alternative.

Comment: Just because there's a hacky workaround doesn't mean you should do it. The HTML spec says no duplicates, then there should be no duplicates.

Comment: I'm not saying you should.  I'm pointing out a technicality of your statement being inaccurate.  Regardless of if something should be done or not, I believe it is always worth while to be aware of the possibilities, and how they affect how "true" the things we say are.

Comment: I'll have to agree to disagree on that one :)